# Using C++ templates to wrap 3rd-party C code

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, hook

I'm writing a library that uses [Function Hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) to inspect the arguments sent from 3rd-party code to a 3rd-party library. The caller and callee are both written in C, and the hooking is accomplished by providing the loader with an array of pairs of function pointers.

Initially, I wrote this in C and duplicated a *lot* of code for each function hook. After writing a handful of hooks, I looked to C++ templates to lighten the load.

The following example works with a fixed number of template arguments and demonstrates the idea:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*PrintCallback)(const char *);

int PrintSingle(const char *input)
{
    return printf("%s", input);
}

template<typename Result,
         typename Arg,
         Result(*callback)(Arg)>
Result WrapFunc(Arg arg)
{
    std::cout << "Logging logic goes here..." << std::endl;
    return callback(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PrintCallback pc = WrapFunc<int, const char *, PrintSingle>;
    pc("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Logging logic goes here...
Hello, World!
```

My trouble comes when I try to use C++11's Variadic Templates to generalize this solution to a variable number of template arguments:

```
template<typename Result,
         typename... Args,
         Result(*callback)(Args...)>
Result WrapFunc(Args... args)
{
    std::cout << "Logging logic goes here..." << std::endl;
    return callback(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

When I try to instantiate this template, it's not clear whether the last template argument is the "callback" value or a part of "Args". My compiler returns this error message:

```
variadic.cpp:22:21: error: address of overloaded function 'WrapFunc' does not
      match required type 'int (const char *)'
        PrintCallback pc = WrapFunc<int,const char *, PrintSingle>;
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
variadic.cpp:14:8: note: candidate template ignored: invalid
      explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Args'
Result WrapFunc(Args... args)
```

However, I can't swap the order of "Args" and "callback" in the template because the callback's type is dependent on the definition of Args.

Is there a way to do this properly, so that I can provide a table of C function pointers to the loader? Solutions that rely on returning std::functions at run-time are off the table, since the calling code won't be able to use them.

Comment: *"with an array of pairs of function pointers"* Beware. Your function has C++ language linkage, your pointer has C++ language linkage but eventually someone expects them to have C language linkage. This will most probably work, but it is an extension (i.e. implementation-defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't really put more parameters after a variadic parameter pack: they try to greedily eat everything. You can often work around this by introducing a layer of indirection, template-style:

```
template <typename Result, typename...Args>
struct Wrap {
    template <Result(*callback)(Args...)>
    static Result Func(Args...args) {
        std::cout << "Logging logic goes here...\n";
        return callback(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

which requires a slight modification of your usage syntax to:

```
PrintCallback pc = Wrap<int, const char *>::Func<PrintSingle>;
```

[See it live at Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69f02381eb347a2e)

Comment: Maybe `template<class T> struct Wrap; template<class Result, class... Args> struct Wrap<Result(Args...)>;` would be more convinient, since it can be invoked as `Wrap< decltype(PrintSingle) >::Func<PrintSingle>`. (It's currently close to the OP, however.)

Answer (score 1):

You may use: (https://ideone.com/OaNtMz)

```
template<typename F, F f, typename... Args>
auto WrapFunc(Args... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    std::cout << "Logging logic goes here..." << std::endl;
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And then:

```
PrintCallback pc = &WrapFunc<decltype(&PrintSingle), &PrintSingle, const char *>;
```

Comment: You can deduce the parameter types from `F`, too.

Comment: @dyp You can, but then how would you expand them in place of `args` in the arguments to `WrapFunc`?

Comment: @Oktalist With another function. Just forward from inside `WrapFunc`.

Comment: @dyp Sorry I don't follow. What would you write in place of `Args&&... args` in the above snippet?

Comment: @Oktalist Hmm looks like I haven't thought this through completely. When trying to implement this, it turns out like Casey's solution, or rather like the comment I added to that. With a variable template, one could probably reduce the syntax back to `WrapFunc<decltype(&PrintSingle), &PrintSingle>`, I guess.

Comment: @dyp: we can't use `Args&&...` here : https://ideone.com/gkR45l . The signature with PrintCallback doesn't match. (and with my solution `Args` is not deduced). So I revert your change.

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm sorry.